# Disable/hide toolbar in NestedList

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

my Friday evening was spent on fighting with unexpected problem) It's about **how to disable native toolbar in NestedList component** (for Sencha touch 2.3.1).

NestedList is created with Toolbar by default. The last one have default configuration:

> toolbar: {docked: 'top', xtype: 'titlebar', ui: 'light', inline: true}

According to API [docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.dataview.NestedList-cfg-toolbar](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.dataview.NestedList-cfg-toolbar) toolbar configuration look's like

> toolbar : Ext.Toolbar/Object/Boolean

so i suppose that Boolean means display (true) or not (false)

Well, let's do some <strike>magic</strike> practice, here is my example:

```
var data = {
     text: 'Groceries',
     items: [{
         text: 'Drinks',
         items: [{
             text: 'Water',
             items: [{
                 text: 'Sparkling',
                 leaf: true
             }, {
                 text: 'Still',
                 leaf: true
             }]
         }, {
             text: 'Coffee',
             leaf: true
         },]
     }, ]
 };

 Ext.define('ListItem', {
     extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
     config: {
         fields: [{
             name: 'text',
             type: 'string'
         }]
     }
 });

 var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
     model: 'ListItem',
     defaultRootProperty: 'items',
     root: data
 });

 var nestedList = Ext.create('Ext.NestedList', {
     fullscreen: true,
     title: 'Groceries',
     displayField: 'text',
     store: store,
     //toolbar: false
 });
```

uncommenting `// toolbar: false` leads to errors, something like

> uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'insert'

and so on. Look's like Sencha try to execute 'insert' method on unexisting component (because it's disabled, toolbar is set to false)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google does not bring me anthing usefull so i was able to fix it by myself.

The problem was hiding in `src/dataview/NestedList.js`

Anyway here is a diff http://www.diffnow.com/?report=o43bd of original file and fixed. Lines ~640 and ~870 are affected.

Your comments are welcome!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a late answser, but I stumbled upon your question and I managed to workaround without any modification to the source files.

Just set `toolbar:{hidden:true}` in the nested list' config.

```
config: {
    // other settings
    toolbar: {hidden: true}
}
```

Let me know if this works for you or if you want me to make a Fiddle!